# How to check if db.Model is changed or not?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to check if db.Model is changed or not. How to do it?

Some example year ago I designed such model and saved:

```
class DeleteMe(db.Model):
  a = db.StringProperty()

key = db.Key().from_path('DeleteMe', 'a')
a = DeleteMe(key = key)
```

After year I was add some new and change default property:

```
class DeleteMe(db.Model):
  a = db.StringProperty(default = 'zero')
  b = db.StringProperty(default = 'cat')

key = db.Key().from_path('DeleteMe', 'a')
a = DeleteMe.get(key)
```

When I am reading model `a == None` and `b == cat` but in datastore `b == None` how can I check if `b == None` in datastore?

I used undocumented `ea = a._entity.get('b')` to check if `ea != a.a` what is alternetive documented method.

Comment: You should check this suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424506/updating-an-ndbs-models-schema/30447673#30447673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't normally check `if b == None` with db or ndb.

What you have suggested is probably the best approach. As you have found the underlying raw entity doesn't even have the `b` property so the default value kicks in. Additionally there is also no index for you can query.

Normally when handling schema migration you have to visit every entity and update it.

In some cases you can do this lazily (ie only update when you next fetch the entity) then your method would be used to establish the actual value or nonexistence of `b` and if the entity needs updating.

You could use a version property in the entity to help manage complex schema updates.

With a version property defined it wouldn't matter if `b == "cat"` because you would know if you need to write back/update the object based on the version of the entities schema.