# How to update an NDB Model's Schema

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have seen the solution to this question using [App Engine's older DB Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema), but cannot find a solution while using the newer **NDB** API.

What is the best way to add migration support, so that I am able to migrate from an old version of a schema to a new version. Would it be best to write a **migration script**, and how would this work?

Something like migrating a schema like this in (Note that the sample is in **NDB**):

```
class Picture(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.StringProperty()
    png_data = ndb.BlobProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty(default='')  # Unique name.
```

To an updated one like this:

```
class Picture(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.StringProperty()
    png_data = ndb.BlobProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty(default='')  # Unique name.

    num_votes = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    avg_rating = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The solution for NDB models is pretty much similar please take a look at solution described in here: [Updating NDB Model's Schema](http://romannowicki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gae/updating-ndb-model-schema.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far as I know, NDB doesn't have any built-in schema migration support. We handle schema migrations this way:

- Add an NDB integer property called `schema_version` to each Model we use. This will be the version of schema that was active when the model was stored.
- Add a class attribute `SCHEMA_VERSION` to each Model, representing the current schema version of the code. It defaults to 0, and we bump this up whenever we add/remove/change NDB properties on the model.
- Have our Models implement a `updateSchema` method that can look at the stored and current versions and perform the appropriate migrations.
- During load of entities, we check to see if the schema version of the entity we loaded is out of date. If it is, we call `updateSchema` to fix up the entity before we return it from our data layer. We then set `schema_version` to the value of `SCHEMA_VERSION`.

This approach means that we are updating the schema on-demand. If we run into a situation where we really want all entities of a particular type to be updated now, we write a map/reduce operation that loads and saves each entity of that type; the schema migration happens automatically as a part of that process, without incurring downtime.

Now, this works unless you are dealing with models with model superclasses whose schemas can also change. To address that, you need to collect the different values of `SCHEMA_VERSION` up the class hierarchy when you come up with a value to store in `schema_version`. We collect them by simply summing them up to come up with the official "current schema version" of the entity, but other ways of doing this are possible.

Comment: Thank you! I will attempt to implement this myself

Comment: Nice Solution Owen. I appreciate you writing this up.